# R extract variables with regex

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I have a character column that needs to be separated with regex. Here is an example of the raw data:

```
data_raw <- tribble(
  ~census_geo,
  "Division No.  1, Subd. V (SNO), Newfoundland and Labrador",
  "Portugal Cove South (T), Newfoundland and Labrador",
  "Division No.  1, Subd. U, Reserve (SNO), Newfoundland and Labrador")
```

We have three columns to be extracted. The first is everything before the brackets. The second column is the word inside the bracket. The last column is everything after the last comma (or everything after the word in the bracket). Here is an example of what the clean output would look like:

```
data_clean <- tribble(
  ~csd_name, ~csd_type, ~province,
  "Division No.  1, Subd. V", "SNO", "Newfoundland and Labrador", 
  "Portugal Cove South", "T",  "Ontario", 
  "Division No.  1, Subd. U, Reserve", "SNO", "Newfoundland and Labrador")
```

I can extract the last column with this code:

```
data_raw %>% 
  mutate(csd_type = str_extract(census_geo, pattern = "(?<=\\().*(?=\\))"))
```

But I can't get the other two columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr`'s `extract` and pass regular expressions to extract the relevant text in different columns.

```
tidyr::extract(data_raw, census_geo, c('csd_name', 'csd_type', 'province'), 
              '(.*) \\((.*)\\),\\s*(.*)')

#  csd_name                          csd_type province                 
#  <chr>                             <chr>    <chr>                    
#1 Division No.  1, Subd. V          SNO      Newfoundland and Labrador
#2 Portugal Cove South               T        Newfoundland and Labrador
#3 Division No.  1, Subd. U, Reserve SNO      Newfoundland and Labrador
```

---

You can achieve the same result in base R with `strcapture` :

```
strcapture('(.*) \\((.*)\\),\\s*(.*)', data_raw$census_geo, 
   proto = list(csd_name = character(), csd_type = character(), 
                province = character()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you already selected Ronak Shah's answer (which was very nice btw), but I wanted to just show an approach with `stringr`'s `separate`:

```
library(stringr)

data_raw %>% 
  separate(
    col = census_geo, 
    into = c('csd_name', 'csd_type', 'province'),
    sep = '(\\s\\(|\\),\\s)'
  )
```

The `\\s` is for the white space, the `\\(` for the parenthesis, and the `|` for splitting the two distinct patterns to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case OP is interested to see how the original approach with `str_extract` would work for all three separate columns using negative character classes `[^)(]`and `[^,]`:

```
data_raw %>% 
  mutate(
    csd_name = str_extract(census_geo, "^[^)(]+(?=\\s)"),
    csd_type = str_extract(census_geo, "(?<=\\()[^)(]+(?=\\))"),
    csd_province = str_extract(census_geo, "(?<=,\\s)[^,]+$")) %>%
  select(-census_geo)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  csd_name                          csd_type csd_province             
  <chr>                             <chr>    <chr>                    
1 Division No.  1, Subd. V          SNO      Newfoundland and Labrador
2 Portugal Cove South               T        Newfoundland and Labrador
3 Division No.  1, Subd. U, Reserve SNO      Newfoundland and Labrador
```